# What does 'their' designate in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

From Article 1 of *GENERAL AGREEMENT ON TRADE IN SERVICES*:

> 3. For the purposes of this Agreement: (a) "measures by Members" means measures taken by: (i) central, regional or local governments and authorities; and (ii) non-governmental bodies in the exercise of powers delegated by central, regional or local governments or authorities;
>
> In fulfilling its obligations and commitments under the Agreement, each Member shall take such reasonable measures as may be available to it to ensure **their** observance by regional and local governments and authorities and non-governmental bodies within its territory.

My question: what does *their* designate in the sentence *ensure **their** observance by regional and local governments and authorities and non-governmental bodies within its territory*?

One scholar said 'their' designates obligations and commitments, but I think it's grammatically awkward.

Can *their* observance instead mean observance of them (that is, one(XX) should observe them), not something that should be observed by them(they should observe something(XX))?

Comment: No, it does mean "obligations and commitments". Even if we wanted to pursue the argument that it meant "their <own> observance", i.e. the individual Member's adherence, that is given the lie by the following clause "regional and local governments and authorities". That is, it is the *regional and local governments and authorities* who need to *observe* the *obligations and commitments* and therefore the antecedent to *their* is and must be those obligations & commitments. Your scholar was correct.

Comment: @DanBron As far as i know, in exceptional cases when , pronoun can precede noun. Why can't 'their' designate "regional and local governments and authorities and non-governmental bodies"?

Comment: what about 'measures'? Can't their designate measures?

Comment: Measures don't *observe* rules. And the rules are being observed *by* regional and local bodies, so they can't be the antecedent to *their*. No, as I said, your scholar was correct.

Comment: I didnt say measures observe rules. i mean measures(instead of obligations and commitments) are observed by regional and local bodies

Comment: No, measures are *how* rules are observed: they're the steps you take in order to ensure observance. You cannot *observe* measures in those sense. I don't have much more to say on this topic. You have my input. Do with it what you like. I'm not going to get into a debate about it.

Comment: Grammar aside, I don't see how it can be r**easonably** interpreted any other way: each signatory State must take steps to ensure internal compliance.

Comment: the real issue is whether 'non-governmental bodies' means "non-governmental bodies in the exercise of powers delegated by central, regional or local governments or authorities" or 'non-governmental bodies' in general. It determines if China breaks the WTO rule when Chinese non-governmental bodies that are not delegated powers by governments don't observe [whatever it is(what im asking in this post].

Comment: @InfimumMaximum It means NGOs in general within the territories controlled by the Member. Basically the clause is trying to say "it is the Member's responsibility to make sure everyone within the territories it controls obeys the rules, governmental and non-governmental alike", but it's being very clear and specific because, well, lawyers. In other words: a parent is responsible for making sure its children behave, sons and daughters alike. This is simply what your quoted text expresses. I am not at all familiar with WTO regulations or Chinese politics, and I have no opinion on those matters.

Comment: Korean side: it means NGOs in general / Chinese side: it means only NGOs delegated power from governments / WTO appellate body judge Peter Van den Bossche said  according to the article above members have the obligation to take all reasonable measures to ensure that ‘sub-national’ levels of government and nongovernmental bodies with delegated governmental powers comply with the obligations under the GATS.

Comment: @InfimumMaximum Oh wait I didn't see he full context you quoted because it wasn't in a blockquote. Doesn't that very specifically say "NGO means NGO exercising a delegated power relevant to this agreement"?

Comment: So I would say it's not that obvious or clear itself. i would say its quite controversial. There is a provision similar to the above article in GATT, "each contracting party shall take such reasonable measures as may be available to it to ensure observance of the provisions of this Agreement by the regional and local governments and authorities within its territories.”, which used 'observance of' instead of 'their observance' so I was trying to intrepret 'their' meaning different from the common interpretation.

Comment: no it never said NGO means NGO exercising a delegated power relevant to this agreement. the first sentences defines meaning of measures, not meaning of NGO. you can't say NGO in the 2nd sentence equals the NGO in the 1st sentence unless there is 'the'.

Comment: @InfimumMaximum No, I'd say it's clear in the full context, because the context before the material you originally quoted specifically set out terms and definitions. Without those definitions, the passage you quoted, standing alone, drew on the more general meanings of the words employed in daily conversation, but the article clearly says those aren't the meanings employed here. Like if this comment said "for the sake of this comment, *no* means *yes*, then the entire meaning of my first sentence would change.

Comment: no. it clearly said that  (1) measures by Members include measures by non-governmental bodies in the exercise of powers delegated by governments and (2) measures by Members excludes measures by non-governmental bodies not in the exercise of powers delegated by governments. But, that's it. It didn't clearly say whether non-governmental bodies  not in the exercise of powers delegated by governments should also observe [XX] as governments and non-gov bodies in the exercise of powers or not.

Answer (score 1):

from comment by OP:

> the real issue is whether 'non-governmental bodies' means
>   "non-governmental bodies in the exercise of powers delegated by
>   central, regional or local governments or authorities" or
>   'non-governmental bodies' in general.

---

Please note that ***non-governmental bodies*** are referenced **twice** in the given quote; once directly:

> ... to ensure [...] observance by regional and local governments and
>   authorities and **non-governmental bodies** within its territory.

and once indirectly:

> ... each Member shall take such reasonable **measures** as may be
>   available to it ...

where ***measures***, we are told, include:

> .. measures taken by: [...] **non-governmental bodies in the exercise of
>   powers delegated by central, regional or local governments or
>   authorities**;

The restriction you ask about applies only to the non-governmental bodies referenced indirectly - i.e those that have the authority to take measures on behalf of the State.

---

To put it in plain terms, the member State must take measures through all its organs (including NGOs that operate on the State's behalf) to ensure compliance by **all** NGOs within its territory.